# Application Scope in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I'm working on a web application using coffeescript.

- I have all classes in separate files.
- The classes refer to few global constants (declared my my app).

I want to create instances of these objects from another file main.coffee.

How can I have the classes and constants under application scope?

Comment: You should post some examples that show how your code is structured.

Comment: Yeah, agree with @AlexWayne. I posted an answer, but now i see the question is tagged with `requirejs`, and if you're using a tool to manage dependencies like that, namespaces don't make too much sense all of a sudden; you can get by using only local variables and it's awesome =D

Answer (score 0):

You either need to compile all your files with the `--bare` option, which make all your classes available through the "global" scope (the `window` variable in a browser environment), or you can define your own `window.MyNamespace = {}` and explicitely make your classes available like:

```
class MyClass
   ...

window.MyNamespace.MyClass = MyClass
```

You've tagged your post `requirejs` which I believe has an even better solution for structuring your modules than either of the suggestions I have given to your question, where each module instance is being explicitely passed, but requirejs is a whole topic on it's own.

Comment: Sorry, for that, I have removed the requirejs tag. I'm looking into requirejs option right now. Will post a separate question for that.

Answer (score 0):

I am note 100% aware how amd works, but despite the `MyNamespace` and the option to compiler with `--bare` you could concat the file into one "large" file before compiling with the coffeescript compiler.

Comment: --bare isn't a good practice I guess. I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers suggest it, but you probably don't want to compile with `--bare`, as it will make *all* the top-level declarations in a file to be global: not only classes but also auxiliary functions, constants, and things that are only used in that file and you probably don't want to put into the global namespace.

Better be explicit and use `class window.MyClass`, which will put *that* class in the global namespace.

Or better yet, if you have a namespace for your application, say, in a file you declare:

```
# Namespace for application stuff.
window.App = {}
```

Then you can put classes in that namespace simply by:

```
# In another file; make sure the first file gets executed before so `App` exists.
class App.MyClass
```

And then you can instantiate and use that class from anywhere by referring to it including its namespace:

```
c = new App.MyClass
c.someMethod()
```

Comment: The problem is my classes use application constants declared in main.coffee. So I'm not sure which files to load first. And having a file with only application constants doesn't look like good option.

Comment: @AkshayAurora It looks like some kind of circular dependency problem them. JS has those problems, especially when considering that files get _executed_ (they are scripts after all). I'd recommend that you take a moment to clearly identify the dependencies and then lay out the classes/modules according to those dependencies.